# Space-time vizualization R

Tags: r, datetime, plot

I have data with number of records, latitude, longtidue, and date. My goal is to use either Google Viz or Shiny to create a map with a scroll bar for time-series. The following is an example of my data.frame in R.

```
  date lat lon num
[1,] 14785 33.47350 -82.01051  174
[2,] 14794 32.75549 -97.33077  904
[3,] 14680 33.74900 -84.38798    7
[4,] 14762 42.90261 -78.74457    1
[5,] 14762 42.01114 -87.84062    1
[6,] 14767 36.37285 -94.20882  152
```

So far, I've been able to produce the following map of all events, but it does not include the time component.

```
library(maps)
map('state',plot = TRUE,col = "grey",fill = F)
points(x = toy$lon, y = toy$lat, col = toy$recs)
title("Events Across America")
```

I'm interested in producing an interactive map with a time-series scroll bar, similar to this graph: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/google-charts.html

I've used the {spatial} and {spacetime} libaries to create a space-time object, but I don't know how to visualize it with the scroll bar. Is this possible? Anything in GoogleViz or Shiny would be great.

```
#### Toy example: ####
toy <- as.data.frame(toy)
toy <-  toy[order(toy$date,decreasing = F),]
coordinates(toy) <- c("lat","lon")
sp <- SpatialPoints(toy)

# Building a spatial data frame:
sp.df <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp, data.frame(recs = toy$recs,date = toy$date))
summary(sp.df)

# Building a Space-time data frame. 
time <- as.POSIXct(toy[["date"]], tz = "GMT")
# to build a space-time object
# data1 has to have sp_n * time_m = n*m rows corresponding to the observations
data1 <- data.frame(recs = rpois(nrow(toy)^2,100))
sptdat <- STFDF(sp,time,data1)
```

Comment: It is unclear whether your data are events (like earthquakes) or time series for fixed locations. Would the gvisMotionChart (example at the end of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spacetime/vignettes/stgvis.html) work for you, when long and lat are taken as x and y?

Comment: The gvisMotionChart is similar what I'm trying to replicate, but instead of having just an long = X and a lat = Y, I'm trying to have a map of the US, so as someone scrolls through time, they can see where the events are taking place. Perhaps similar to the Irish Wind in Time Annotation plot, but instead of the specific graph demonstrated, we can have a map.

Comment: If your data are events, it is not similar to the wind data: unlike events, wind speed has everywhere and at every moment in time a value.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the plotKML package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotKML/index.html) to visualize my STIDF point object. 
The plotKML function can read objects created with the spacetime package. It creates a kml-file which can be read in Google Earth. Google Earth has a time slider in with which you can easily assess your space-time data. You can use both raster and vector data.